# Как сделать что бы нижний график стал меньше по высоте, а верхний больше в R?

Tags: графика, r, plotly

Как сделать что бы нижний график стал меньше по высоте, а верхний больше в R?

```
library(plotly)
library(plyr)
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B"), each=200)),
                                    rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
cdat <- ddply(dat, "cond", summarise, rating.mean=mean(rating))

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.3, colour="black", fill="white") +
    facet_grid(cond ~ .) +
    geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=rating.mean), linetype="dashed", size=1, colour="red")

fig <- ggplotly(p)
fig
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите увеличить масштаб оси у:

```
draw<-function(dat1, height,cdat1)
{
 ggplot(dat1, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.3, colour="black", fill="white") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,height)) + 
  geom_vline(data=cdat1, aes(xintercept=rating.mean), linetype="dashed", size=1, colour="red")
}
p1<-draw(dat %>% filter(dat$cond=="A"),60,cdat %>% filter(cdat$cond=="A"))
p2<-draw(dat %>% filter(dat$cond=="B"),35,cdat %>% filter(cdat$cond=="B"))
ggarrange(p1,p2,ncol = 1,nrow = 2)
```

Если просто разный масштаб - откажитесь от facet и ggarrange, выводите отдельно p1 и p2